# JSON Parse error: Problem deserializing property 'taxLevels' (expected type: [map

Tags: java, jackson

I am deserializing json:

```
"taxLevels": [{
        "code": "VAT",
        "percentage": 19.0
    }
]
```

I have Model class:

```
public class Model{

   @JsonDeserialize(using = TTaxLevelDeserializer.class)
    private final List<TTaxLevel> taxLevels = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This is TTaxLevel.class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TTaxLevel {

    private String code;
    private Double percentage;
}
```

I had to write custom deserializer because there were error:

> [Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
> `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>` out of
> START_ARRAY token; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of
> `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>` out of
> START_ARRAY token  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 36,
> column: 19] (through reference chain: ...Model["taxLevels"])]]

```
public class TTaxLevelDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<TTaxLevel>>{

    @Override
    public List<TTaxLevel> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        List<TTaxLevel> tTaxLevels = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(new TypeReference<List<TTaxLevel>>(){}).readValue(node);
        return tTaxLevels;
    }

}
```

Now it returns proper `List<TTaxLevel> tTaxLevels` but I have error:

> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Problem deserializing property 'taxLevels' (expected
> type: [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class
> java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]]; actual
> type: `java.util.ArrayList`), problem: argument type mismatch; nested
> exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
> Problem deserializing property 'taxLevels' (expected type: [map type;
> class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple
> type, class java.lang.String]]; actual type: `java.util.ArrayList`),
> problem: argument type mismatch  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream);
> line: 40, column: 5] (through reference chain:
> ...Model["taxLevels"])]]

Why is it expecting Map?
Is there any option to force it to deserialize it as List?

Comment: You don’t need a custom deserializer.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar what do you suggest? I have error without it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Map data structure instead of List

```
Map<String,List<TTaxLevel>>
```

Comment: There are about 50 references of it and I will have to change the code. Is there any other option to treat it as ArrayList instead of Map?